# Treat NESTED sub-projects in folders as child folders in IIS website in IntelliSense (ie. inherit web.config from root project)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nested, web-config

There is a *large* ASP.NET web project, made up of many tens of thousands of files developed over the years.

The effective hierarchy looks as:

```
Site\All.sln
Site\root.csproj
Site\web.config
...
Site\Sub1\sub1.csproj
Site\Sub1\web.config <-- inherits from Site\web.config at runtime;
                         tell IntelliSense to do the same
Site\Sub1\page.aspx
...
Site\Sub1\Sub1a\sub1a.csproj
...
Site\Sub2\sub2.csproj
...
Site\bin <-- all assemblies compiled to here
```

The back-end code compiles fine and the project runs `page.aspx` without errors, as when executed IIS understands the nested web.configs (ie. `Site\web.config` is the *root* config and `Site\Sub1\web.config` inherits from the root config).

However, when editing `page.aspx` (as part of the `Sub1` project) in Visual Studio 2022, **IntelliSense is reporting errors** (ie. 'assembly not referenced') because it does not understand `Site\Sub1\web.config` is a child web configuration that will inherit from the parent web.config.

There are other issue as well, such as not seeing/understanding the `<system.codedom>` (root web.config change to enable Roslyn) and/or that `Site\bin` is where the assemblies will be loaded from (which break aspx editor highlighting when non-SN shared assemblies are added to `<assemblies>`).

*Without* moving all the projects into the top-level folder:

- Is it possible to get Visual Studio to apply the web.config *as though* it was actually running?
- Similarly, is it possible to get Visual Studio to understand 'Sub1/Page.aspx' (not 'Page.aspx') is the relative path when the site is deployed?

---

A significant reason to not moving all the project files to the root folder, besides a fair bit of tedious semi-automated effort, is that it is very hard for VS to handle a 'show all files' in such a scenario. It is also painful (slow and management issue) to negate paths in SDK-style projects.

Comment: Actually, the SDK projects (in VS 22) are fast when starting with     `<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);**</DefaultItemExcludes>`. Still leaves the "extra" folder structures and much non-related Solutions items on an expand-all.

Comment: Still a bit spotty to try and use SDK-style projects for Web Forms.. supports is not official, although short of the designer magic (including not even being able to add from templates) it appears to work OK.

Comment: Well, shoot. With multiple projects in one folder there are issues with package restoring.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the project and select the pre-build event/post-build event command line dialog box in the project properties.

You can use any of these macros to specify locations for files, or to get the actual name of the input file in the case of multiple selections. These macros are not case-sensitive.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/pre-build-event-post-build-event-command-line-dialog-box?view=vs-2022#macros

Comment: The code works fine when deployed and the web.config inheritance is desired. The issue is that VS is not aware that the child projects *are also* child folders in the real application and _should_ inherit from the web.config (in the parent directory above the .csproj). The sub-projects are never run directly from VS and the entire web-application, of all the different projects/folders, is already running on a local IIS instance.

Comment: I'll update my answer based on your prompt.